# Android create Bitmap + crop causing OutOfMemory error(eventually)

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, crop

I am taking 3 pictures in my app before uploading it to a remote server. The output is a byteArray. I am currently converting this byteArray to a bitmap, performing cropping on it(cropping the centre square). I eventually run out of memory(that is after exiting the app coming back,performing the same steps). I am trying to re-use the bitmap object using BitmapFactory.Options as mentioned in  the android dev guide

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ioFW3cyRV0&list=LLntRvRsglL14LdaudoRQMHg&index=2

and

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsQet4nBVi8&list=LLntRvRsglL14LdaudoRQMHg&index=3

This is the function I call when I'm saving the image taken by the camera.

```
public void saveImageToDisk(Context context, byte[] imageByteArray, String photoPath, BitmapFactory.Options options) {
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.length, options);
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
    int dimension = getSquareCropDimensionForBitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight);
    Log.d(TAG, "Width : " + dimension);
    Log.d(TAG, "Height : " + dimension);
    //bitmap = cropBitmapToSquare(bitmap);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByteArray, 0,
            imageByteArray.length, options);
    options.inBitmap = bitmap;

    bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, dimension, dimension,
            ThumbnailUtils.OPTIONS_RECYCLE_INPUT);
    options.inSampleSize = 1;

    Log.d(TAG, "After square crop Width : " + options.inBitmap.getWidth());
    Log.d(TAG, "After square crop Height : " + options.inBitmap.getHeight());
    byte[] croppedImageByteArray = convertBitmapToByteArray(bitmap);
    options = null;

    File photo = new File(photoPath);
    if (photo.exists()) {
        photo.delete();
    }


    try {
        FileOutputStream e = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(e);
        bos.write(croppedImageByteArray);
        bos.flush();
        e.getFD().sync();
        bos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

}


public int getSquareCropDimensionForBitmap(int width, int height) {
    //If the bitmap is wider than it is tall
    //use the height as the square crop dimension
    int dimension;
    if (width >= height) {
        dimension = height;
    }
    //If the bitmap is taller than it is wide
    //use the width as the square crop dimension
    else {
        dimension = width;
    }
    return dimension;
}


 public Bitmap cropBitmapToSquare(Bitmap source) {
    int h = source.getHeight();
    int w = source.getWidth();
    if (w >= h) {
        source = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, w / 2 - h / 2, 0, h, h);
    } else {
        source = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, h / 2 - w / 2, w, w);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "After crop Width : " + source.getWidth());
    Log.d(TAG, "After crop Height : " + source.getHeight());

    return source;
}
```

How do I correctly recycle or re-use bitmaps because as of now I am getting OutOfMemory errors?

**UPDATE :**

After implementing Colin's solution. I am running into an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

My logs are below

```
08-26 01:45:01.895    3600-3648/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-1
Process: com.test.test, PID: 3600
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=556337; index=556337
        at com.test.test.helpers.Utils.test(Utils.java:197)
        at com.test.test.fragments.DemoCameraFragment.saveImageToDisk(DemoCameraFragment.java:297)
        at com.test.test.fragments.DemoCameraFragment_.access$101(DemoCameraFragment_.java:30)
        at com.test.test.fragments.DemoCameraFragment_$5.execute(DemoCameraFragment_.java:159)
        at org.androidannotations.api.BackgroundExecutor$Task.run(BackgroundExecutor.java:401)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

P.S : I had thought of cropping byteArrays before, but I did not know how to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to do any conversion to bitmaps, actually.
Remember that your bitmap image data is [RGBA_8888](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html#RGBA_8888) formatted. Meaning that every 4 contiguous bytes represents one pixel. As such:

```
// helpers to make sanity
int halfWidth = imgWidth >> 1;
int halfHeight = imgHeight >> 1;
int halfDim = dimension >> 1;

// get our min and max crop locations
int minX = halfWidth - halfDim;
int minY = halfHeight - halfDim;
int maxX = halfWidth + halfDim;
int maxY = halfHeight + halfDim;

// allocate our thumbnail; It's WxH*(4 bits per pixel)
byte[] outArray = new byte[dimension * dimension * 4]

int outPtr = 0;
for(int y = minY; y< maxY; y++)
{
    for(int x = minX; x < maxX; x++)
    {
        int srcLocation = (y * imgWidth) + (x * 4);
        outArray[outPtr + 0] = imageByteArray[srcLocation +0]; // read R
        outArray[outPtr + 1] = imageByteArray[srcLocation +1]; // read G
        outArray[outPtr + 2] = imageByteArray[srcLocation +2]; // read B
        outArray[outPtr + 3] = imageByteArray[srcLocation +3]; // read A
        outPtr+=4;
    }   
}
//outArray now contains the cropped pixels.
```

The end result is that you can do cropping by hand by just copying out the pixels you're looking for, rather than allocating a new bitmap object, and then converting that back to a byte array.

== EDIT:

Actually; The above algorithm is assuming that your input data is the raw RGBA_8888 pixel data. But it sounds like, instead, your input byte array is the *encoded JPG data*. As such, your 2nd decodeByteArray is actually decoding your JPG file to the RGBA_8888 format. If this is the case, the proper thing to do for re-sizing is to use the techniques described in "[Most memory efficient way to resize bitmaps on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121058/most-memory-efficient-way-to-resize-bitmaps-on-android)" since you're working with encoded data.

Comment: Hi Colt. I am running into an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, in the loop. I have edited the question and added the log for the same. 
   Could you clarify what imgWidth and width are? I have taken width to be the total bitmap width which we get when we decode it. I am assuming imgWidth is the same. 
   Also  the value of outPtr does not change. Should there not be an increment based on iteration?  Thank you so much for your response!

Comment: updated the code to move outptr forward, and also update srclocation with something more accurate. ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException just means that outArray or imageByteArray is being indexed at a location greater than it's length.

Comment: The byteArray is actually the output of the camera(Commonsware's CWAC Camera). The camera has set picture format to 256 i.e JPEG. JPEGs do not have transparency(alpha channel). So does this matter?

Comment: When an image is loaded into memory from a decode process it's always converted to RGBA8888, regardless if it has transparency or not.

Comment: Thanks Colt. Any idea as to why I'm getting the index out of bounds exception? This is a hurdle I have not been able to get past.

Comment: outArray should be a subset of imageByteArray, from what I understand. When I print the lengths of the two arrays, the length of  outArray is greater than the imageByteArray(which is the  i/p array). This does not seem right to me.

Comment: 08-27 07:41:03.525    2828-2866/com.test.test D/Utils﹕ imageByteArray length : 279582
                                                                                                                       08-27 07:41:03.529    2828-2866/com.test.test D/Utils﹕ outArray length : 3686400

Comment: Please see the edit in my answer; I believe that your input data is the compressed JPG bytes, rather than the RGBA_8888 bytes, which should change what you're doing. My original assumption was that the input was raw byte data, and you were converting it to a bitmap for resizing; But it appears that may not be the case.

Comment: Debugged this :      imageByteArray length : 335132                                             imageHeight : 1200    imageWidth : 1600     dimension : 1200                            halfWidth :  800  halfHeight : 600   halfDim:600                                                  minX:200   minY : 0   maxX: 1400    maxY : 1200                                             outArray length : 5760000 (i.e dimension * dimension * 4).  Yes it is compressed data!! Not raw byte data.

Comment: Thanks again Colt. Will definitely check out that thread. Perf matters!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting more and more variables to `null` - this helps reclaiming that memory;

after

```
 byte[] croppedImageByteArray = convertBitmapToByteArray(bitmap);
```

do:

```
bitmap= null;
```

after

```
 FileOutputStream e = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
```

do

```
photo = null;
```

and after

```
 try {
        FileOutputStream e = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(e);
        bos.write(croppedImageByteArray);
        bos.flush();
        e.getFD().sync();
        bos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

do:

```
e = null;
bos = null;
```

Edit #1

If this fails to help, your only real solution actually using memory monitor. To learn more go [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ls28uGMBEs)

Ps. there is another very dark solution, very dark solution. Only for those who know how to navigate thru dark corners of ofheapmemory. But you will have to follow this path on your own.

Comment: This did not help with the issue @Adam