# Android: Creating a splashscreen on app start WITHOUT timer?

Tags: android, android-studio

Currently I have a very low-res splashscreen I made by setting the applications theme to a drawable image. This would work PERFECTLY if it wasn't for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301697/android-extreme-lag-when-using-high-resolution-drawables). Now I'm looking for an alternative.

The one thing I will not do is create a timed splashscreen, which there are plenty of guidelines on how to make one, the one thing I want to know is how do I create a splashscreen that will load first thing, then finish once `MainActivity` has finished loading?

The one thing I love about my current splashscreen is that it loads instantly when the app starts, but it will cause major delays when clicking buttons if it's high-res (more than 300x300pixels).

Here's my current code for the flawed, laggy splashscreen that loads and stops based on `MainActivity`'s loaded state:

in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="splashscreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
    </style>
in manifest:
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/splashscreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for possible issues with overdraw. It seems that the background (the splash image) is still there. see http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/01/android-performance-case-study/ if it applies to your case.

> Removing the window background: the background defined in your theme is used by the system to create preview windows when launching your application. Never set it to null unless your application is transparent. Instead, set it to the color/image you want or get rid of from onCreate() by calling getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null).