# We use a lot of ImageButton and the App lag

Tags: java, android

for my little game i use a lot of Image Buttons! The problem is that the application is lagging on some mobiles..but i dont find the problem.

Here is a Screenshot that you can imagine it better:

[image]

Now the question is how I got it running smoothly ? Pls i need our help :)
Here is the menu xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="de.unikatproduktion.smaragdhunter.MenueActivity"
android:background="@drawable/menuehintergrund">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_zurvollversion"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/btnzurvollversion"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/smaragdmenueanim"
        android:id="@+id/imgshhg"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/btnmusikanaus"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonmusikanausnewclickeddddd"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="275dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/zauberermenue"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/zauberermenuehgg"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_highscore"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_appbewerten"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_appbewerten"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="221dp"
        android:layout_width="60dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_appbewerten"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/btnappbewerten"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_start"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/btnstart"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_highscore"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn_highscore"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="375dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="220dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/schwierigkeitsgrad"
        android:background="@drawable/btnschwierigkeit"
        android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
        android:scrollbarSize="100dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
        android:animationCache="false"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="false"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:dropDownSelector="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
        android:popupElevation="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Die Vollversion bietet ein besseres Spielerlebnis!"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/werbeview"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btnenglisch"
        android:id="@+id/sprache"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/insta"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/instaiconklein" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Check the size of your images, be sure they are not bigger than you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reuse your bitmaps , so it doesn't have to be decoded every time the user opens your game.
You can use `InBitmap` in `BitmapFactory.Options`like in this code :

```
public class ImageCache {

Set<SoftReference<Bitmap>> mReusableBitmaps;

protected Bitmap getBitmapFromReusableSet(BitmapFactory.Options options) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    if (mReusableBitmaps != null && !mReusableBitmaps.isEmpty()) {
        synchronized (mReusableBitmaps) {
            final Iterator<SoftReference<Bitmap>> iterator
                    = mReusableBitmaps.iterator();
            Bitmap item;

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                item = iterator.next().get();

                if (null != item && item.isMutable()) {
                    // Check to see it the item can be used for inBitmap.
                    if (canUseForInBitmap(item, options)) {
                        bitmap = item;

                        // Remove from reusable set so it can't be used again.
                        iterator.remove();
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    // Remove from the set if the reference has been cleared.
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}

int getBytesPerPixel(Bitmap.Config config) {
    if (config == Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888) {
        return 4;
    } else if (config == Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) {
        return 2;
    } else if (config == Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444) {
        return 2;
    } else if (config == Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 1;
}
public boolean canUseForInBitmap(Bitmap candidate, BitmapFactory.Options targetOptions) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        // From Android 4.4 (KitKat) onward we can re-use if the byte size of
        // the new bitmap is smaller than the reusable bitmap candidate
        // allocation byte count.
        int width = targetOptions.outWidth / targetOptions.inSampleSize;
        int height = targetOptions.outHeight / targetOptions.inSampleSize;
        int byteCount = width * height * getBytesPerPixel(candidate.getConfig());
        return byteCount <= candidate.getAllocationByteCount();
    }

    // On earlier versions, the dimensions must match exactly and the inSampleSize must be 1
    return candidate.getWidth() == targetOptions.outWidth
            && candidate.getHeight() == targetOptions.outHeight
            && targetOptions.inSampleSize == 1;
}

public void addInBitmapOptions(BitmapFactory.Options options) {
    // inBitmap only works with mutable bitmaps, so force the decoder to
    // return mutable bitmaps.
    options.inMutable = true;

    if (this != null) {
        // Try to find a bitmap to use for inBitmap.
        Bitmap inBitmap = getBitmapFromReusableSet(options);

        if (inBitmap != null) {
            // If a suitable bitmap has been found, set it as the value of
            // inBitmap.
            options.inBitmap = inBitmap;
        }
    }
}
public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(Resources res,int id) {

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id , options);

    // If we're running on Honeycomb or newer, try to use inBitmap.
    addInBitmapOptions(options);

    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id ,options);
}
```

I hope this works for you :) , and if not you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121058/most-memory-efficient-way-to-resize-bitmaps-on-android)

Comment: okay thank you! :) I just need to create a new class and paste this code?

Comment: ya , something like this : `bitmap = new ImageCache.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(getResources , R.drawable.your_img);`

Comment: puhhh okay i am a beginner i will try it..if I can not do it can you help me maybe? i can send you all my stuff

Comment: Sure , But First do you understand what does this code do ? Second  , you don't need to send me your stuff :)

Comment: You can explain again what the code does exactly if it's okay.. And what must I exactly in the code change

Comment: Okay , what happens is: It checks if this bitmap was decoded before or not by checking in caches , if there is , load it using `InBitmap` otherwise decode the bitmap. sounds good ? now try it and compare the difference in performance if you still have the lagging , check  the link in my answer.

Comment: Oh I forgot to add something , add this to your Manifest in Application section :  `android:largeHeap="true"` maybe that will help

Comment: okay thanks :) And in which place in the class I must declare my pictures?

Comment: The `ImageCache` class should have a file for itself , so what you have to do is just call the method `decodeSampledBitmapFromFile` like this : `ImageCache ic = new ImageCache(); Bitmap yourPic = ic.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(getResources , R.drawable.your_pic);`

Comment: Yes but in which class at which place should I call this line

Comment: The class you are using to set Bitmap of your image buttons

Comment: ImageButton insta = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.insta);
        Bitmap bitmap = new ImageCache().decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(getResources(), R.drawable.instaiconklein);
        insta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (leseSound()==0 || leseSound()==1) {
                    btnbuttonsound.start();
                    vibe.vibrate(20);
                    menuemusik.stop();        like this?

Comment: you forgot to add this : `insta.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139910/discussion-between-hesham-haikal-and-jordy).

Comment: Android Studio doesnt find setImageBitmap

Answer (score 4):

It usually happens when the images have high resolutions. It could be the case that you have one `ImageView` in the whole app that could make the app crash as the device faces an overhead trying to render it.

Comment: And how can I adjust the resolution of the images on the different mobile phones?

Comment: You can do it using [9-patch-resizer](https://github.com/redwarp/9-patch-resizer) tool, which takes a large resolution image and generate same images with lower resolutions for different screen densities. Therefore, you can put the generated images in the `res` folder of your project and the app will use the appropriate image at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on 'Profile GPU rendering' in Settings/Developer options to see whether it is the rendering at all, that makes your app lag.