# App is crashed when getting bitmaps and adding a list

Tags: android, list, bitmap, drawable

I try to get images from drawable and add a list. But in debugging It stops after I have taken a few photos(sometimes 20,22..).and it gives **SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x430000))** error in debug screen.
In logcat screen it gives **Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 80409612 byte allocation with 16767792 free bytes and 72MB until OOM"**
I have changed photos' sizes but it still crash.What should I do?

There is my code block that I take photos:

```
for (int j = 0; j < imagesName.length; j++) {
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier(imagesName[j], "drawable", getPackageName()));
        bitmaps.add(((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap());
    }
```

Comment: why are you converted those images in to Bitmap object? what you want to achieve can you elaborate that

Comment: I am working on image processing in OpenCv. I converted my images to Mat for some processes, Opencv have functions with bitmaps for this converting. @shahid17june

Comment: Try to use Picasso or Retrofit library. They are good at managing cache and memory.

Comment: But I want to use my own photos like vegetables, fruits etc.. @Akshay

Comment: @shahid17june  I think that couldn't take image as a Mat. But I can. It worked faster,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can add below entities in your manifest file android:hardwareAccelerated="false" , android:largeHeap="true" it will work for some environment's.

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: I tried it before,but it didn't solve my problem @Dora

Comment: Still it isn't working although converting to png format @Dora

Comment: I checked it again, it worked for more than 20 images. I crashes again when came to 37. image. Despite working,it will be difficult to convert all the photos into png format when my dataset be larger.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use inSampleSize to load a down-scaled bitmap version. Please refer to this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32121059/1107579

Comment: there isn't any efficient solution for my problem @RayChongJH